# Getting "execute" permission for an area of memory

Tags: c++, memory

I am using C++, and would like to get the permission to execute on an area of memory. Is there a way I can do this? Right now when I just try to execute it, I get an access violation error.

Comment: platform? operating system? how are you trying to execute data?

Comment: Windows 7 home premium 64 bit. I thought of a neat way to execute dynamic assembly:

    typedef void(*funcptr)();
    
    /* Moves 1 into ebx and returns */
    char funcbody[8] = {'\xbb', '\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xc3'};
    void* tmp = funcbody;
    
    funcptr f = (funcptr)tmp;
    f();

but I get a memory access violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the function is [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), you'll want to pass in [PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get execute permission.

By default Windows does not allow memory.  It's called [Data Execute Prevention (DEP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366553%28VS.85%29.aspx).