# How to create code emmiter in c++

Tags: c++

I am triying to create a code emmiter in c++ in order to learn how to make an emulator, but im having a hard time making dynamic assembler  work:

```
unsigned char program[] = {0x90,  0x90, 0xC3 }; //nop; nop; ret
void (*p)(void) =  (void(*)())     &program;
p();
```

always return access violation .....

im working with visual studio 2012 C++ win32 console application

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to cast a char[] to a pointer to a function?? why? I think i don't understand what are you trying to do...

Comment: Does the memory which holds `program` permit execution?

Comment: woah I want to know the answer too.

Comment: this is an example, but the char array is a buffer where all the instructions are going to be stored and then processed by the cpu:
http://www.multigesture.net/wp-content/uploads/mirror/zenogais/Dynamic%20Recompiler.html

Comment: Does windows allow these kinds of shenanigans?

Comment: @CarlNorum: Certainly.  How else can a JITter work?

Comment: Sure; I meant without a further dance to allow execution (ala @GamErix's answer).

Comment: @CarlNorum: before DEP (which depended on the support of the NX bit in the processor) memory was executable by default. Also, DEP has been disabled by default for anything but system services for several Windows releases to avoid breaking applications that relied on this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research I found this:
you have to allocate the memory and change the read/write/execution permissions to: Allow Read, Disallow Write, Allow Execution.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251790/getting-execute-permission-for-an-area-of-memory) question for a "how to do it".

> On Windows the function is [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), you'll want to pass in [PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get execute permission.
>
> By default Windows does not allow memory execution.  It's called [Data Execute Prevention (DEP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366553%28VS.85%29.aspx).

And [for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125756/allocate-executable-ram-in-c-on-linux):

> See mprotect(). Once you have filled a (n-)page-sized memory region (allocated with mmap()) with code, change its permissions to disallow writes and allow execution.

another fix for your issue on windows is just [add your program to DEP whitelist](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-vista/change-data-execution-prevention-settings)... (You probbly didn't notice, but your crash is probably of type `BEX`, `BEX` crashes are in 99% cases related to DEP)

P.S. When you create a working code emitter.. mind giving me a copy? xD

Comment: @David O_O so much stuff to download, don't know where to start xD